# Windows 10 slow after support call

Tags: windows, windows-10

I flashed a new, Dell-certified BIOS after installing an ATI FirePro m7820 in my Dell Precision m6400. After the flash (I had to boot from FreeDOS), Windows said it was not activated. Then I spent 3 hours on a tech support call, and eventually Windows was re-activated. I used the built in app to contact them, then they used LogMeIn Rescue to remotely access my PC. Windows is activated now (Windows 10 Pro) but the UI has some serious framerate issues. After the call, when I click the action center or even the Windows key, All the icons no longer have that smooth travel that they had before the support call. Even when Windows was not activated, it ran fine.
Is it the remote assistance software? Should I reinstall?
(One of the first things she did was delete everything in my Temp folder. Also, she rebooted the laptop the first time, it said "working on Updates.")

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your video card driver? And making sure they are up to date?

Comment: I have never in 20 years of using Microsoft products, heard of them using LogMeIn Rescue, whom ever connected to your PC was NOT MICROSOFT.  There is built in software into Windows they MIGHT use but I personally have never had anyone from Microsoft request to even do that.

Comment: I have also never known Dell to do this.  What you describe is a common trick by scam artist.  Why you would call Dell for Windows activation issues, I have no idea, helpful if you clarify who you called exactly.

Comment: It was not a scam, I contacted them through the built-in Windows 10 "Contact Support" app. And my video card driver is up-to-date and working.

Comment: And they also used a custom version of LogMeIn rescue from the official Microsoft website.

Comment: Also, I didn't "call" anyone, per se. I used the contact support app, and there is no voice chat. Sorry if that was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind everyone, I reinstalled my graphics drivers and it solved the issue.